# Как заменить ключ в объекте правильно?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Подскажите плз., как заменить dirName на условно newName?

```
var options = {
    "dirName": {
        "pages": 2,
        "template": {
            "html": "templates/some.html",
            "styles": [
                "css/some.css"
            ],
            "script": "js/default.js",
            "sounds": {
                "start": "sounds/start.mp3",
                "end": "sounds/end.mp3"
            }
        }
    },
    "theSome": {
        "downloadURL": "some.pdf"
    }
}
```

Comment: добавить новый и удалить старый.

Comment: никак. в объекте нельзя изменять ключи

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1444435/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE/1444441#comment2578643_1444435)

> никак. в объекте нельзя изменять ключи

Но мы можем перенести значения старых данных в новый ключ и удалить старый:

```
options.newName = options.dirName; // "Копируем" старые данные в новый ключ
delete options.dirName; // Удаляем ключ
```

```js
var options = {
  "dirName": {
    "pages": 2,
    "template": {
      "html": "templates/some.html",
      "styles": [
        "css/some.css"
      ],
      "script": "js/default.js",
      "sounds": {
        "start": "sounds/start.mp3",
        "end": "sounds/end.mp3"
      }
    }
  },
  "theSome": {
    "downloadURL": "some.pdf"
  }
};

// REPLACE KEY
options.newName = options.dirName;
delete options.dirName;

console.info(options);
```

Либо можно написать функцию, для замены имён, если такое выполнять придётся чаще.
Написано под ES6

```js
function RenameKey(o, old_key, new_key) {
  if(old_key !== new_key) {
    Object.defineProperty(o, new_key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, old_key));
    delete o[old_key];
  }
}

var options = {
  "dirName": {
    "pages": 2,
    "template": {
      "html": "templates/some.html",
      "styles": [
        "css/some.css"
      ],
      "script": "js/default.js",
      "sounds": {
        "start": "sounds/start.mp3",
        "end": "sounds/end.mp3"
      }
    }
  },
  "theSome": {
    "downloadURL": "some.pdf"
  }
}

RenameKey(options, 'dirName', 'newName');

console.info(options);
```